# take a part from a string without a specific pattern

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, plyr, tidyr

I have a column where in

cell.1 is "UNIV ZURICH;NOTREPORTED;NOTREPORTED;NOTREPORTED" 
cell.2 is "UNIBG"

```
 s = c("UNIV ZURICH;NOTREPORTED;NOTREPORTED;NOTREPORTED", "UNIBG")
 s1 = unlist(strsplit(s, split=';', fixed=TRUE))[1]
 s1
```

and I want to get

```
cell.1 UNIV ZURICH
cell.2 UNIBG
```

many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = c("UNIV ZURICH;NOTREPORTED;NOTREPORTED;NOTREPORTED", "UNIBG")
s1 = strsplit(s, split=';')
result = data.frame(mycol = unlist(lapply(s1, function(x){x[1]})))

> result
        mycol
1 UNIV ZURICH
2       UNIBG
```

Comment: @SeymaKalay: Would you mind marking the answer as correct then?

Answer (score 1):

Your `strplit()` approach is a good idea, it gives:

```
strsplit(s, split=';', fixed=TRUE)                                
[[1]]
[1] "UNIV ZURICH" "NOTREPORTED" "NOTREPORTED" "NOTREPORTED"

[[2]]
[1] "UNIBG"
```

In order to get what you are looking for, you need to extract the first element of each element of the list you obtained and then merge them, here is a way to do so (btw, `fixed=TRUE` is now required for this example).

```
s1 <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(s, split=';', fixed=TRUE), `[`, 1))
```

Previously, you were merging all elements in one list:

```
unlist(strsplit(s, split=';', fixed=TRUE))                        
[1] "UNIV ZURICH" "NOTREPORTED" "NOTREPORTED" "NOTREPORTED"
[5] "UNIBG"
```

and then you were taking the first element of this vector.

Comment: A short explanation of your change would be helpful.

Comment: Indeed! Plus some ` were missing